# How to get how many PhoneAuth used Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase blaze plan. How can I get how many Phone Auth (SMS) used and how many left in this month with API request?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to retrieve the usage details of phone authentication. The quota/usage is only available in the Firebase console.

You can find the information in the [Authentication > Usage tab of your Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/usage/current-billing).

[image: screenshot of the Firebase Authentication Usage console]

If you're actually using phone number verification, your chart will look more interesting than mine above. :)

Comment: Yes, bro I know that. But I didn't ask how to get by accessing website. I just need from get information from API

Comment: "I know that" -> You might want to update your question with that information.